# Let $a_k=\dfrac{x^k}{k!}$ Show that $\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\leq\dfrac12$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Fix $x\geq0$ and let $a_k=\dfrac{x^k}{k!}$
Show that $\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\leq\dfrac12$ for sufficiently large k, say $k\geq N$

Comment: I get it equalling x/(k+1) but the inequalities throw me.

Comment: So, for a given x, what N would you choose so that all numbers above that are higher than twice x?

Comment: k >= 2x - 1 Would that be right?

Comment: Close. You can be generous here and choose any $N \ge 2x$.

Comment: Also, the second part of the question asks to find a suitable expression for N, if we require N ≥ 1.

Comment: I don't understand here: what's the relation between $\,S_n\,$ **and the question** about the sequence  $\,\{a_n\}\,$  ??

Comment: http://i479.photobucket.com/albums/rr160/Luxio404/SafariScreenSnapz004.png

Comment: @Shysonata: In other words: none.

Comment: I have to wonder why the question's author allows $x=0$ when considering the fraction $a_{k+1}/a_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's note that $ \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{x^k}{k!}}=\frac{x}{k+1} $

Let's note that for any fixed x, $ \exists k\in \mathbb{N}: \frac{x}{k+1}\leq \frac{1}{2} $
because, we can choose $ 2x-1 \leq k $